# How do I make a button with CSS

Tags: css, button

How do I make a button with CSS to look like this?

[image: this]

I've tried, but I can't imagine how should I make bottom line with borders like this.. My result: http://jsfiddle.net/UPpfw/

```
.button_push{
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 189px;
height: 54px;
display: block;    
}
.button_green{
    background: #4ec9a6;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #00a09a;
}
```

i've solve the problem and the solve was: http://jsfiddle.net/TmQzX/

```
.button_push{
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
width: 189px;
height: 54px;
display: block;    
text-align: center;
line-height: 47px;
text-decoration: none;
}
.button_white{
    background: #4ec9a6;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 189px;
    height: 49px;
    display: block;
}
.try_button{
    width: 189px;
    height: 54px;
    position: relative;
    top: 212px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Go to the page where the button is. Inspect element using firebug. Steal the code. ;)

Comment: The bottom border looks the same on your jsFiddle as the example. What, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: no, the bottom border have himself top borders.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UPpfw/4/)?

I figured out that you need shadow for your button. and instead of `border-bottom: 7px solid #00a09a;`

I suggest use of box shadow

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 3px -2px #00a09a;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 3px -2px #00A09A;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 3px -2px #00A09A;
```

Answer (score 0):

Css:

```
.button_push{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 189px;
    height: 54px;
    line-height:54px;
    display: block;    
}
.button_green{
    background: #4ec9a6;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #00a09a;
    text-align:center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UPpfw/6/

Comment: thanks for try but if you look closier you will see, that the bottom border have himself top borders..

Comment: What exactly you need. Do you want a smooth effect. @baitas212123